# Text-based fighting game in Python 3.0

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, role-playing-game, battle-simulation

I have began to practice Python after a couple of years and for my first Project, i decided to make a fighting/rpg-like game with different characters. So far, I am only familiar with loops and functions, not classes or OOP. Please give me any feedback on how I could improve my code, through debugging, optimization, or adding more content (In case the game doesn't start due to the absence of highscore.txt, please make a text file called highscore, and of the first line insert an interger, and on the second put any name. This should not happen, but just in case :P).

```
import random as r

######Getting High Score#####

try:
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r+")
except:

    hs = open("highscore.txt","x")
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r+")

try:
    score = hs.readlines(1)
    score = int(score[0])

    leader = hs.readlines(2)
    leader = str(leader[0])
except:
    hs = open("highscore.txt","w")
    hs.write("0\n")
    hs.write("null")
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r")
    score = hs.readlines(1)
    score = int(score[0])
    leader = hs.readlines(2)
    leader = str(leader[0])

#####Introduction, Initializing player#####

print("\nWELCOME TO WONDERLANDS RPG!")
print("The High Score is:",score,"by",leader)
points = 0
player_name = input("\nEnter your hero's name: ")

#####Classes [health, attack 1 (only does set damage), attack 2 min, attack 2 max, attack 3 min, attack 3 max, heal min, heal max], Getting player's Class#####

knight = [100,10,5,15,0,25,5,10] #health: 100, attack 1: 10, attack 2: 5-15, attack 3: 5-25, heal: 5-10
mage = [50,15,10,20,-5,25,10,15] #health: 50, attack 1: 15, attack 2: 10-20, attack 3: -5-25, heal: 10-15
healer = [150,5,5,10,5,15,10,20] #health: 150, attack 1: 5, attack 2: 5-10, attack 3: 5-15, heal: 10-20

while True:
    print("\n1. Knight: Health: ",knight[0],"; Attack 1:",knight[1],"; Attack 2:",knight[2],"-",knight[3],"; Attack 3:",knight[4],"-",knight[5],"; Heal:",knight[6],"-",knight[7])
    print("2. Mage: Health: ",mage[0],"; Attack 1:",mage[1],"; Attack 2:",mage[2],"-",mage[3],"; Attack 3:",mage[4],"-",mage[5],"; Heal:",mage[6],"-",mage[7])
    print("3. Healer: Health: ",healer[0],"; Attack 1:",healer[1],"; Attack 2:",healer[2],"-",healer[3],"; Attack 3:",healer[4],"-",healer[5],"; Heal:",healer[6],"-",healer[7])
    player_class = input("\nSelect your class: 1, 2, or 3: ")
    if player_class == "1":
        player_class = knight
        print("You have selected the Knight")
        break
    if player_class == "2":
        player_class = mage
        print("You have selected the Mage")
        break
    if player_class == "3":
        player_class = healer
        print("You have selected the Healer")
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a valid class.")
        continue

player_heal_max = player_class[0]

#####Difficulty/Upgrade Functions#####

def level_up(player,health_max):
    while True:
        lv_choice = input("\nWould you like to:\n Increase max health by 20 (1)\n Increase Healing Factor by 5 (2)\n increase your damage by 5 (3) ")
        if lv_choice == "1":
            health_max += 20
            player[0] = health_max
            return player,health_max
        elif lv_choice == "2":
            player[6] +=5
            player[7] +=5
            player[0] = health_max
            return player, health_max
        elif lv_choice == "3":
            player[1] +=5
            player[2] +=5
            player[3] +=5
            player[4] +=5
            player[5] +=5
            player[0] = health_max
            return player, health_max
        else:
            print("Please enter in a valid number")
            continue

def difficulty(ai,health_max,level):
    if level == 1:
        return ai
    else:
        ai[0] = health_max+15*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[1] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[2] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[3] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[4] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[5] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[6] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        ai[7] +=5*round(0.5*level+0.5)
        return ai

def ai_stats(s):
    s[0] += r.randint(-20,20)
    s[1] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[2] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[3] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[4] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[5] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[6] += r.randint(-3,3)
    s[7] += r.randint(-3,3)
    return s

#####Game Loop#####

level = 1
print("\n----------------------- GAME START -----------------------")

while True:
    #####Determining AI Class/Stats#####
    #####(AI classes must be in the Game loop otherwise if an enemy chooses the same class twice, it would have <=0 HP, thus being an instant win)#####
    ai_knight = [100,10,5,15,0,25,5,10] #health: 100, attack 1: 10, attack 2: 5-15, attack 3: 5-25, heal: 5-10
    ai_mage = [50,15,10,20,-5,25,10,15] #health: 50, attack 1: 15, attack 2: 10-20, attack 3: -5-25, heal: 10-15
    ai_healer = [150,5,5,10,5,15,10,20] #health: 150, attack 1: 5, attack 2: 5-10, attack 3: 5-15, heal: 10-20

    ai = r.randint(1,3)
    if ai == 1:
        ai = ai_stats(ai_knight)
        print("\nYou are fighiting a knight with",ai[0],"HP!")
    if ai == 2:
        ai = ai_stats(ai_mage)
        print("\nYou are fighiting a mage with",ai[0],"HP!")
    if ai == 3:
        ai = ai_stats(ai_healer)
        print("\nYou are fighiting a healer with",ai[0],"HP!")

    ai_heal_max = ai[0]
    ai = difficulty(ai,ai_heal_max,level)
    #####Gameplay Loop#####
    while True:
        #####Player Attack#####
        player_move = input("\nWould you like to use attack (1), attack (2), attack (3), or heal (4)? ")
        print("")
        if player_move == "1":
            player_damage = player_class[1]
            ai[0] = ai[0]- player_damage
            print(player_name," did",player_damage,"damage!")
        elif player_move == "2":
            player_damage = r.randint(player_class[2],player_class[3])
            ai[0] = ai[0]- player_damage
            print(player_name," did",player_damage,"damage!")
        elif player_move == "3":
            player_damage = r.randint(player_class[4],player_class[5])
            if player_damage<0:
                player_class[0] = player_class[0]+player_damage
                print(player_name," damaged themselves for",player_damage,"HP!")
            else:
                ai[0] = ai[0]- player_damage
                print(player_name," did",player_damage,"damage!")
        elif player_move == "4":
            player_heal = r.randint(player_class[6],player_class[7])
            if player_class[0] + player_heal > player_heal_max:
                player_class[0] = player_heal_max
            else:
                player_class[0] = player_class[0] + player_heal
            print(player_name," healed for",player_heal,"HP")
        else:
            print("Please enter in a valid move.")
            continue
        #####Detecting Death#####
        if player_class[0]<=0:
            break
        elif ai[0]<=0:
            points += player_class[0]*level
            level +=1
            print("You have bested your opponent! You Have",points,"points. \nNow starting level",level)
            player_class,player_heal_max = level_up(player_class,player_heal_max)
            break
        #####AI Turn#####
        if ai[0] <= (ai_heal_max/5):
            ai_move = r.sample(set([1,2,3,4,4,4]), 1)[0]
        elif ai[0] >= (ai_heal_max*.8):
            ai_move = r.sample(set([1,2,3,1,2,3,4]), 1)[0]
        elif ai[0] == ai_heal_max:
            ai_move = r.randint(1,3)
        else:
            ai_move = r.randint(1,4)

        if ai_move == 1:
            ai_damage = ai[1]
            player_class[0] = player_class[0]- ai_damage
            print("Your opponent did",ai_damage,"damage!")
        elif ai_move == 2:
            ai_damage = r.randint(ai[2],ai[3])
            player_class[0] = player_class[0]- ai_damage
            print("Your opponent did",ai_damage,"damage!")
        elif ai_move == 3:
            ai_damage = r.randint(ai[4],ai[5])
            if ai_damage<0:
                ai[0] = ai[0]+ai_damage
                print("Your opponent damaged themselves for",ai_damage,"HP!")
            else:
                player_class[0] = player_class[0]- ai_damage
                print("Your opponent did",ai_damage,"damage!")
        elif ai_move == 4:
            ai_heal = r.randint(ai[6],ai[7])
            if ai[0] + ai_heal > ai_heal_max:
                ai[0] = ai_heal_max
            else:
                ai[0] = ai[0] + ai_heal
            print("Your opponent healed for",ai_heal,"HP")
        #####Displaying HP#####   
        print("\nYour health is:",player_class[0],"HP")
        print("Your opponent's health is",ai[0],"HP")
        #####Detecting Loss#####
        if player_class[0]<=0:
            break
        elif ai[0]<=0:
            points += player_class[0]*level
            level +=1
            print("You have bested your opponent! You Have",points,"points. \nNow starting level",level)
            player_class,player_heal_max = level_up(player_class,player_heal_max)
            break
        else:
            continue
    #####Finishing Game, Checking/Updating High Score#####
    if player_class[0]<=0:
        print("\nYou Died! :(")
        if points>score:
            hs = open("highscore.txt","w")
            hs.write(str(points))
            hs.write("\n")
            print("You have the new high score of",points,"!")
            hs.write(player_name)
        else:
            print("\nYou finished with",points,"points.")
            print("The high score is:",score,"by",leader)
        input("")
        hs.close()
        break
```

Comment: Really cool game here. Thanks for sharing. Expect an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your game, which I've played, you have 3 main warriors: knight, mage, and healer.  These warriors all have similar behaviors, health, attacks, and heals - *they are essentially objects of a class*, `Warrior`.

**Tip 1:** Let's create a `Warrior` class:

- You will be able to create new Warriors (ie Archers, Brutes, Zombies) later with ease.
- You can interface your AI player as a Warrior.
- You can simply control all of your Warrior objects.

```py
class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health, attack_1, attack_2, attack_3, heal):
        self.health = health
        self.attack_1 = attack_1
        self.attack_2 = attack_2 # tuple ie (5,25) representing range for attack value
        self.attack_3 = attack_3 # tuple ie (10,20) representing range for attack value
        self.heal = heal # tuple ie (10,20) representing range for health value

    def attributes(self):
        # string containing the attributes of the character
        string = "Health: "+ str(self.health) + " Attack 1: "+ str(self.attack_1) + " Attack 2: "+ str(self.attack_2[0]) + "-"+ str(self.attack_2[1])+ " Attack 3: "+ str(self.attack_3[0]) + "-"+ str(self.attack_3[1]) + " Heal:"+ str(self.heal[0]) + "-" + str(self.heal[0])
        return string

    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0
```

You may want to add other functions later. For instance, `def attack_3(self)`, which would return the value of an attack.  We then initialize the knight, mage, healer, and ai as so:

```
knight = Warrior(100, 10, (5,15),  (5,25),  (5,10))
mage   = Warrior(50,  15, (10,20), (-5,25), (10,15))
healer = Warrior(150, 5,  (5,10),  (5,15),  (10,20))

while True:
    # Determining AI Class/Stats
    ai_knight = Warrior(100, 10, (5,15),  (5,25),  (5,10))
    ai_mage   = Warrior(50,  15, (10,20), (-5,25), (10,15))
    ai_healer = Warrior(150, 5,  (5,10),  (5,15),  (10,20))
    ai_classes = [ai_knight, ai_mage, ai_healer]

    ai = ai_classes[r.randint(0,2)]
    randomize_ai(ai)
    if ai == ai_knight:
        print("\nYou are fighting a knight with ", ai.health,"HP!")
    elif ai == ai_mage:
        print("\nYou are fighting a mage with ", ai.health,"HP!")
    elif ai == ai_healer:
        print("\nYou are fighting a healer with ", ai.health,"HP!")
```

**Tip 2:** `elif` is your best friend. If your `if` statements are mutually exclusive, you can cut down on the complexity of your program, by using `elif`(which you used successfully in your program, just not always):

```
if ai == 1:
    #code
if ai == 2:
    #code
if ai == 3:
   #code

# should instead be...
# because ai can't be three values at once

if ai == 1:
    #code
elif ai == 2:
    #code
elif ai == 3:
   #code
```

**Tip 3:** The style in which you program is critical to your actual program.  A few basic things you should know about coding styles:

- Do not use too many `#` when you are commenting. Instead of `######Displaying HP#######` try `# Display HP`. The latter is more readable for someone else or yourself reading/reviewing your code.
- If you have a section header comment, you can try a special commenting style such as:

```py
###########
# CLASSES #
###########
```

- Do not add extra spaces to your code -- this makes your code longer than it *needs to* and *should* be.  Make your code shorter if it doesn't reduce readability.
- To improve the user experience, avoid typos when possible
- And whatever you do, be consistent. It's easiest to read, review, and edit code that is consistent in style.
- Style is one of those things that just takes experience and practice. You will get better over time.

**With these three tips in mind, your final code should look more like:**

````
import random as r

try:
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r+")
except:
    hs = open("highscore.txt","x")
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r+")

try:
    score = int(hs.readlines(1)[0])
    score = int(score[0])
    leader = hs.readlines(2)
    leader =  str(hs.readlines(2)[0])
except:
    hs = open("highscore.txt","w")
    hs.write("0\nnull")
    hs = open("highscore.txt","r")
    score = int(hs.readlines(1)[0])
    leader = str(hs.readlines(2)[0])

# Introduce and name the player
print ("\nWELCOME TO WONDERLANDS RPG!")
print ("The High Score is:", score, "by", leader)
points = 0
player_name = input ("\nEnter your hero's name: ")


###########
# CLASSES #
###########

class Warrior:
    def __init__(self, health, attack_1, attack_2, attack_3, heal):
        self.health = health
        self.attack_1 = attack_1
        self.attack_2 = attack_2 # tuple ie (5,25) representing range for attack value
        self.attack_3 = attack_3 # tuple ie (10,20) representing range for attack value
        self.heal = heal # tuple ie (10,20) representing range for health value

    def attributes(self):
        # string containing the attributes of the character
        string = "Health: "+ str(self.health) + " Attack 1: "+ str(self.attack_1) + " Attack 2: "+ str(self.attack_2[0]) + "-"+ str(self.attack_2[1])+ " Attack 3: "+ str(self.attack_3[0]) + "-"+ str(self.attack_3[1]) + " Heal:"+ str(self.heal[0]) + "-" + str(self.heal[0])
        return string

    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

knight = Warrior(100, 10, (5,15),  (5,25),  (5,10))
mage   = Warrior(50,  15, (10,20), (-5,25), (10,15))
healer = Warrior(150, 5,  (5,10),  (5,15),  (10,20))

while True:
    print("\n1. Knight: ", knight.attributes())
    print("\n2. Mage:   ", mage.attributes())
    print("\n3. Healer: ", healer.attributes())
    player_class = input("\nSelect your class: 1, 2, or 3: ")
    if player_class == "1":
        player_class = knight
        print("You have selected the Knight class.")
        break
    elif player_class == "2":
        player_class = mage
        print("You have selected the Mage")
        break
    elif player_class == "3":
        player_class = healer
        print("You have selected the Healer")
        break
    else:
        print("Please select a valid class.")
        continue

player_heal_max = player_class.health


################################
# Difficulty/Upgrade Functions #
################################

def level_up(player,health_max):
    while True:
        lv_choice = input("\nWould you like to:\n 1. Increase max health by 20 \n 2. Increase Healing Factor by 5 \n 3. increase your damage by 5\n")
        if lv_choice == "1":
            health_max += 20
            player.health = health_max
            return player, health_max
        elif lv_choice == "2":
            player.heal += (5,5)
            player.health = health_max
            return player, health_max
        elif lv_choice == "3":
            player.attack_1 += 5
            player.attack_2 += (5,5)
            player.attack_3 += (5,5)
            player.health = health_max
            return player, health_max
        else:
            print("Please enter in a valid number")
            continue

def difficulty(ai,health_max,level):
    if level == 1:
        return ai
    else:
        ai.health = health_max + 15 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5)
        ai.attack_1 += 5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5)
        ai.attack_2 += (5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5),5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5))
        ai.attack_3 += (5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5),5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5))
        ai.heal += (5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5),5 * round(0.5 * level + 0.5))
        return ai

def randomize_ai(ai):
    ai.health += r.randint(-20,20)
    ai.attack_1 += r.randint(-3,3)
    ai.attack_2 += (r.randint(-3,3),r.randint(-3,3))
    ai.attack_3 += (r.randint(-3,3),r.randint(-3,3))
    ai.heal += (r.randint(-3,3),r.randint(-3,3))
    return ai

#############
# Game Loop #
#############

level = 1
print("\n----------------------- GAME START -----------------------")

while True:
    # Determining AI Class/Stats
    ai_knight = Warrior(100, 10, (5,15),  (5,25),  (5,10))
    ai_mage   = Warrior(50,  15, (10,20), (-5,25), (10,15))
    ai_healer = Warrior(150, 5,  (5,10),  (5,15),  (10,20))
    ai_classes = [ai_knight, ai_mage, ai_healer]

    ai = ai_classes[r.randint(0,2)]
    randomize_ai(ai)
    if ai == ai_knight:
        print("\nYou are fighting a knight with ", ai.health,"HP!")
    elif ai == ai_mage:
        print("\nYou are fighting a mage with ", ai.health,"HP!")
    elif ai == ai_healer:
        print("\nYou are fighting a healer with ", ai.health,"HP!")

    ai_heal_max = ai.health

    ai = difficulty(ai, ai_heal_max, level)

    # Gameplay Loop
    while True:
        # Player Attack
        player_move = input("\nWould you like to use attack (1), attack (2), attack (3), or heal (4)?  ")
        print("")
        if player_move == "1":
            player_damage = player_class.attack_1
            ai.health = ai.health - player_damage
            print(player_name," did",player_damage,"damage!")
        elif player_move == "2":
            player_damage = r.randint(player_class.attack_2[0],player_class.attack_2[1])
            ai.health = ai.health - player_damage
            print(player_name," did",player_damage,"damage!")
        elif player_move == "3":
            player_damage = r.randint(player_class.attack_3[0],player_class.attack_3[1])
            ai.health = ai.health - player_damage
            print(player_name," did", player_damage, " damage!")
        elif player_move == "4":
            player_heal = r.randint(player_class.heal[0],player_class.heal[1])
            if player_class.health + player_heal > player_heal_max:
                player_class.health = player_heal_max
            else:
                player_class.health = player_class.health + player_heal
            print(player_name," healed for",player_heal,"HP")
        else:
            print("Please enter in a valid move.")
            continue

        # Detecting Death
        if player_class.is_dead():
            break
        elif ai.is_dead():
            points += player_class.health * level
            level += 1
            print("You have bested your opponent! You Have",points,"points. \nNow starting level",level)
            player_class, player_heal_max = level_up(player_class,player_heal_max)
            break

        # AI Turn
        if ai.health <= (ai_heal_max/5):
            ai_move = r.sample(set([1,2,3,4,4,4]), 1)[0]
        elif ai.health >= (ai_heal_max*.8):
            ai_move = r.sample(set([1,2,3,1,2,3,4]), 1)[0]
        elif ai.health == ai_heal_max:
            ai_move = r.randint(1,3)
        else:
            ai_move = r.randint(1,4)

        if ai_move == 1:
            ai_damage = ai.attack_1
            player_class.health = player_class.health - ai_damage
            print("Your opponent did",ai_damage,"damage!")
        elif ai_move == 2:
            ai_damage = r.randint(ai.attack_2[0],ai.attack_2[1])
            player_class.health = player_class.health- ai_damage
            print("Your opponent did ",ai_damage," damage!")
        elif ai_move == 3:
            ai_damage = r.randint(ai.attack_3[0],ai.attack_3[1])
            player_class.health = player_class.health - ai_damage
            print("Your opponent did ", ai_damage," damage!")
        elif ai_move == 4:
            ai_heal = r.randint(ai.heal[0],ai.heal[1])
            if ai.health + ai_heal > ai_heal_max:
                ai.health = ai_heal_max
            else:
                ai.health = ai.health + ai_heal
            print("Your opponent healed for ", ai_heal," HP")

        # Displaying HP  
        print("\nYour health is:", player_class.health,"HP")
        print("Your opponent's health is ", ai.health," HP ")

        # Detecting Death
        if player_class.is_dead():
            break
        elif ai.health <= 0:
            points += player_class.health * level
            level += 1
            print("You have bested your opponent! You Have",points,"points. \nNow starting level",level)
            player_class, player_heal_max = level_up(player_class,player_heal_max)
            break

    # Finishing Game, Checking/Updating High Score
    if player_class.health<=0:
        print(" \ nYou Died !: (")
        if points > score:
            hs = open(" highscore.txt "," w ")
            hs.write(str(points))
            hs.write(" \ n ")
            print(" You have the new high score of ",points," !")
            hs.write(player_name)
        else:
            print(" \ nYou finished with ",points," points.")
            print(" The high score is:",score," by ",leader)
        input(" ")
        hs.close()
        break
```
````

Comment: I made lots of other small edits. If you're curious about one of them, leave a comment and I'll be sure to respond.